# using jquery mask plugin with on() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

Is it possible to use mask function with "on()" event?

my jquery code for masking:

```
$("#ktel,#kmob").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

what i need is something like this:

```
$("#ktel,#kmob").on("mask","(999) 999-9999");
```

Comment: No, because `mask` is not an event.  What specifically are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm working on a site that has some controls, which are added to page after a couple of events by scripts. so, mask function for that controls doesnt work.

Comment: Some code on this would have been useful, but based on your description: You could call mask on these elements within the handlers where you add these elements. (Hope this makes sense)

Comment: could you give me a simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function bindMask(c){
  $(c).mask("(999) 999-9999");
}
```

It is impossible , you should call bind action every time

Answer (score 1):

It is not a javascript event. But custom plugin. So you must call like that.

Comment: I mean you must call

$("#ktel,#kmob").mask("(999) 999-9999");

Since its a plugin you cant use 'on' function

Answer (score 0):

this helped me
Here is an example I used to have mask work on DOM change for editing fields

```
      $(document).on('dblclick', '.data', function(){

    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var value = $(this).html();

    /*
    * PROVIDE MASK FILTERS IF APPLICABLE
    */
    $(this).html("<input id='editing' type='text' class='data' name='"+name+"' value='"+value+"'>");
    if(name == 'phone'){
      $('#editing').mask('(999) 999-9999');
    }
    if(name == 'postal'){
      //alert('ur in postal');
      $('#editing').inputmask('a9a 9a9');
    }
......code continues
```